# Compile directive with conditional template before it is appended to body

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Assume I have a directive for with conditional template:

```
app.directive('postContent', function ($compile) {
  var template = ''
  var text = '<ANY>template for text</ANY>';
  var image = '<ANY>template for image</ANY>';
  var video = '<ANY>template for video</ANY>';
  var compiler = function ($element, $attrs) {
    if (condition1) {
     template = video;
    } else if(condition2) {
     template = image;      
    } else {
     template = text;
   }
  }

  var templateElem = angular.element(template);
  $element.after(templateElem);
  $element.remove();
  var subLink = $compile(templateElem);
  return {
    pre: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      subLink(scope);
    },
    post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
  }

});
```

**condition1 and condition2 are too complicated to be implementable in view.**
This works fine if condition1 and condition2 are static, but the problem is,the conditions I use are over the scope and I don't have scope on compiler function. how should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, "too complicated condition" can be abstracted away in a function, or computed once and stored in a variable:

```
link: function(scope){
  scope.condition1 = doVeryComplicatedLogic();
  scope.condition2 = function(){
     return doAnotherComplicatedLogic(scope.param);
  }
}
```

template:

```
<any ng-if="condition1">template for video</any>
<any ng-if="condition2()">template for image</any>
<any ng-if="!condition1 && !condition2()">template for text</any>
```

But, if you insist, you could conditionally compile/link the template in the `link` function:

```
link: function(scope, element){
   var tmpl = text; 
   if (condition1){
      tmpl = video;
   } else if (condition2){
      tmpl = image;
   }

   element.append(tmpl);
   $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, the first approach was the one I used. But the implementation in the link function is a low performance way, and depending on the growth of data in scope and of course the html of template we're working on, it could be time consuming.

Comment: Which part is time consuming, I didn't get?